# Can I define an enum into a Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

into a C# .cshtml view I have the following code that define a C# code snippet:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterPageMobile.cshtml";
}
```

Can I also define an `enum` into this section?

Comment: You should probably explain your problem a bit better and we could maybe suggest a solution, otherwise expect a lot of "no" answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't.

The code inside the `@{ }` elements is generated into methods, which can't contain `class`, `enum` and other definitions.

See this sample:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    int x = "abc";
}
```

Is compiled to:

```
public override void Execute() {
    #line 1 "c:\xxx\WebApplication3\Views\Home\Index.cshtml"

    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    int x = "abc";
}
```

Comment: +1 for great explanation.

Comment: Sorry but this is incorrect.  See my answer.

Answer (score 12):

You actually can do this now in Razor, using the `@functions` section.  Here's an example that works:

```
@using Web.Main.Models

@model RoomModel

@functions {
    enum PageModes {
        Create,
        Edit,
    }
}

@{
    // Based on what model we've been passed, we can determine whether we're dealing with an existing room (which
    // we'll want to edit) or a new room (which we'll want to create).
    PageModes pageMode;
    if (Model is CreateRoomModel)
    {
        pageMode = PageModes.Create;
    }
    else if (Model is EditRoomModel)
    {
        pageMode = PageModes.Edit;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("View model not recognized as valid for this page!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.